# Como reiniciar un JFrame en Java sin Cerrarlo?

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación en `Java`, la cual después que realiza un proceso, necesito que se reinicie, pero que no se cierre.

Es decir: necesito que todos los componentes tomen el estado incial, como cuando el `JFrame` se abre por primera vez.

¿Alguien sabe que método dedo utilizar o si se puede?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personalmente, creo que si quieres limpiar el contenido deberás asignar los valores iniciales

```
public static void main(String s[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel("Pon algo aqui");

    final JTextField texto = new JTextField();
    texto.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    JButton boton = new JButton();
    boton.setText("Resetear datos");

    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              texto.setText(null);
          }
        });

    panel.add(etiqueta);
    panel.add(texto);
    panel.add(boton);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

En este ejemplo solo tienes un campo pero el funcionamiento será el mismo:

Rellenas campo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando aprietas el boton: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTAS:

- los elementos a modificar dentro del listener deben ser finales
- si tienes muchos elementos crea un metodo aparte

Comment: El problema es que, el Jframe tiene un lector de Huella Digital, el cual al limpiar los demas componentes no se reincia, este mantiene su configuracion, hasta el momento he logrado trabajarlo cerrando y creando una nueva instancia del jframe, es por eso que pregunto si se puede reiniciar Jframe, y de ser posible este ejecutaria el metodo WindowsOpened ?

Comment: Si no pones nada de codigo, no te podremos ayudar mas

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
removeAll()//or remove(JComponent)
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Fue una respuesta de una pregunta similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260855/how-to-clear-reset-a-jframe

Answer (score 0):

Si todo lo que quieres hacer es conseguir que sus componentes en su estado inicial, entonces tal vez todo lo que necesita es eliminar todos los componentes de texto. Podrias utilizar el restart(), removeAll(), repaint(), depende de lo que desees hacer...

Saludos!!!

Comment: Necesito que todos los componentes tomen el estado incial, es decir como cuando el JFrame se abre por primera vez, con implementacion de los metodos restart(), removeAll(), repaint(), se invocara el metodo WindowsOpened del JFrame nuevamente?